# Unable to replace the left side navigation, to show only my metadata nagivation tree

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, custom-masterpage, aspx

I was reading about showing the metadata navigation tree as my left side navigation, i found this link which describe how to implement a similar task http://markuspersson.wordpress.com/tag/managed-metadata/ . but when i added the following at the beginning of my EnterpriseWiki.aspx page using SharePoint designer :-

```
<%@ Register Src="/_Controltemplates/MetadataNavTree.ascx" 
                TagName="MetadataNav" 
                TagPrefix="SharePoint" %>
```

and the following at the end :-

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:MetadataNav ID="Metadatanav1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

The navigation is shown as follow inside my SharePoint site [link](http://postimg.org/image/k68qiq8mr/)

So i have the following question:-

1. how i can show the full navigation tree.
2. how i can add a custom redirect inside my page layout or in some control ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `MetadataNavigationTree` only displays when you are on a page/list/library which has Metadata configured - All Publishing lists and libraries has this as well as the system pages by default.
2. There exist many ways. Most common is a hidden webpart (HTML Form Web Part) with some javascript.

Comment: can you advice what do you mean by "MetadataNavigationTree only displays when you are on a page/list/library which has Metadata configured -" . and why in my case the Tree did not show  ?

Comment: if all the libraries have this by defualt ?